# Node JS Async requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

I have over 500,000 URLs stored in the collection(users2) like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c0ae729a9109fc1af36680"),    
    "application_url" : "http://example.com/"
 },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c0ae729a9109fc1af36685"),    
    "application_url" : "http://example.com/"
 }
 .....
```

The Node JS server must get the "application_url" of each document alter it and generate a new url before making a request.
 It must do so in order, and it must wait for each response before moving onto the next URL (when a new request will be made).
 The final result (which happen to be JSON) need to stored in a collection.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
```

exports.getDetails=function (req,res){

```
console.log("getDetails");

var sequence = Promise.resolve();

req.db.Users2.find({},{application_url:1,_id:0}).exec().then(function(result) {                       

                        return result.reduce(function(sequence, applicationUrl) {

                            return sequence.then(function() {                             
                                //return applicationUrl;
                                //console.log(applicationUrl.application_url);

                                actualUrl = applicationUrl.application_url;

                                console.log("actualUrl::"+actualUrl);

                                var splitUrl = actualUrl.toString().split('/');
                                var splitid = (splitUrl[5]+"").split('?');
                                var getId = splitid[0];
                                var id = getId.substring(2);
                                var newUrl = splitUrl[0]+'//'+splitUrl[2]+'/'+'lookup?id='+id;

                                //console.log("newUrl::"+newUrl);

                                return newUrl;

                            }).then(function(newUrl) {

                                console.log("newUrl::"+newUrl);     

                                request(newUrl).then(function(response,body){
                                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

                                })



                            });
                        }, Promise.resolve());

                }).then(function() {    

                    console.log("Done");

                }).catch(function(err) {

                    console.log("Error");

                })
```

}

I am able to work out till new url generation and have no idea how to make a request wait till response is received before moving onto the next url using promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `return`. You will have to return the promise from the `then` callback, otherwise it won't wait for it, and resolve with `undefined` immediately.

```
return result.reduce(function(sequence, applicationUrl) {
    return sequence.then(function() {
        var actualUrl = applicationUrl.application_url;
        console.log("actualUrl::" + actualUrl);
        var splitUrl = actualUrl.toString().split('/');
        var splitid = (splitUrl[5] + "").split('?');
        var getId = splitid[0];
        var id = getId.substring(2);
        var newUrl = splitUrl[0] + '//' + splitUrl[2] + '/' + 'lookup?id=' + id;
//      return newUrl;           <-- these are pretty superfluous, btw
//  }).then(function(newUrl) {   <-´
        console.log("newUrl::" + newUrl);
        return request(newUrl).then(function(response, body) {
//      ^^^^^^
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        })
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```